# Different look of application in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I'm developing a game with libgdx. I have a samsung infuse 4g and the game in my computer looks big but in my cellphone looks the way that i want to looks.

But when I run the application on the android machine simulator on eclipse it looks like on my computer: big

I'm using API_7 and I don't understand why. the size of my character is 128px,64px. I'm using Wide side and when I create the stage using libgdx I put this.

```
stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),true);
```

Comment: if the Resoltion is higher your character get smaller because your stage always has the max resolution but your character still stays at its size. Resize the character and the stage on resize to a procentual for example and it should look the same. Else you need to provide some more informations so we  can help you.

Comment: Ok, I made my character on photoshop, and it has 128x64 pxeles, but i dont change his size, I just use the default size, you mean that I have to change his size, to look alike on all the screans ?

Comment: yes sure. if you have a bigger screen with higher resolution you cant keep it 128x64. Well sure you can but its really small than. So you need to resize your character depending on the resolution of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Resoltion is higher your character get smaller because your stage always has the max resolution but your character still stays at its size. Resize the character and the stage on resize to a procentual for example and it should look the same. Else you need to provide some more informations so we can help

A small example would be. if you have a resolution of 1280x640 your char would be 10% of the screen right? Now imagin the resolution would be 640x320. Your character would be 20% of the screen. so you need to make it smaller to have the same proportion at the smaller screen. 
At a bigger one you need to make it bigger for the same proportion. Use the

```
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
..... //resize here depending on the width and the height
    }
```

in your screen to resize. I would recomend to use a `OrthographicCamera` which you give your stage `stage.setCamera(cam);`. So you just need to change the `camera viewport` in the resize and your stage does fit right. But keep track of the `aspect_ratio`.

---

You can even start working with a fixed resolution. So you have a resolution you work with and the rest is done by the `zoom` of your camera.

 To have a fixed resolution you do zoom in and out with your camera to always have the whole resolution on the `screen`. It depend on the resolution your screen has. So if the resolution is smaller(of the screen where you display the game) you zoom out to show the whole gamefield. Else you zoom in till there is one edge at the viewport edges.(puh this seems to be hard stuff) Okay how does looks this?

```
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        Gdx.app.log("Screen", "Resize screen: " + getName());
        cam.viewportHeight = height;
        cam.viewportWidth = width;
        if (Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH / cam.viewportWidth < Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT
                / cam.viewportHeight) {
            cam.zoom = Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT / cam.viewportHeight;
        } else {
            cam.zoom = Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH / cam.viewportWidth;
        }
        cam.update(); // update it ;)
    }
```

This is actually everything. The `VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH` and `VIRTUAL_VIEW_HEIGHT`are the resolution in `px` where i do work with at my game hud. Take care to use the right camera. So this is the camera that i gave my stage.

Maybe take a look at this [blog](http://steigert.blogspot.de/). He does explain everything you need to know about Sceen2d and how to resize and so on.